# Configure Azure endpoint so that it works only for specific urls

Tags: azure, endpoint

My Cloud App has two roles with public endpoint. One of them is on https and second on http. Both of them should be configured to be available on the same TLD, let's say `example.com`. However though, there's a catch:

1. Http endpoint should respond only to `http://example.com` (let's say for now that calls to `http://something.example.com` can be redirected to `https://something.example.com`).
2. Https endpoint on the other hand should work the opposite way: calls without subdomains should be redirected to `http://example.com`.

Is there an easy way to to this by configuring some redirects in cscfg or something?

Answer (score 0):

Any specific reason why you have 2 cloud web roles, Cant you have a single web role and both these application hosted on the same web role as different applications exposing 80, 443 out. This way you can control the redirection easily.

Comment: The first role - the one that should work only on http - is a simple asp web site so role is set as Web Role, the second role is more facilitated application written primarily as C# console app and then adapted to be run as a Worker Role. Now I need to secure both endpoints so that they answer only for address that is planned but Cloud Service runs them just by IP (the same) and port (obviously different). Worst case scenario is adding simple check conditions in app and in controller but I thought there should be some better solution here...